# yum install glibc and prompt broken package

Tags: linux, rpm, glibc, yum

I want to upgrade glibc, when I run the command `yum install glibc`, I get such response.

```
Error: Package: libopencore-amrnb0-0.1.3-1.fc20.i686 (@/libopencore-   amrnb0-0.1.3-1.fc20.i686)
Requires: /usr/sbin/ldconfig
Removing: glibc-2.18-16.fc20.i686 (@updates)
           Not found
       Updated By: glibc-2.18-19.fc20.i686 (updates)
          Not found


Error: Package: libx264_138-0.138-19_20130917.2245.fc20_80.i686 (@/libx264_138-0.138-19_20130917.2245.fc20_80.i686)
       Requires: /usr/sbin/ldconfig
       Removing: glibc-2.18-16.fc20.i686 (@updates)
           Not found
       Updated By: glibc-2.18-19.fc20.i686 (updates)
           Not found

Error: Package: libmad0-0.15.1b-4.fc20.i686 (@/libmad0-0.15.1b-4.fc20.i686)
       Requires: /usr/sbin/ldconfig
       Removing: glibc-2.18-16.fc20.i686 (@updates)
           Not found
       Updated By: glibc-2.18-19.fc20.i686 (updates)
           Not found

You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Then

```
$ rpm -qv glibc
glibc-2.18-16.fc20.i686
glibc-2.18-16.fc20.x86_64
```

Then

```
$ rpm -qp glibc
error: open of glibc failed: No such file or directory
```

Did anyone have the similar problem, and know how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want upgrade a package with `yum`, then must use the `upgrade` command, like this:

```
yum upgrade glibc
```

And from the `yum` manual:

```
-p, --package PACKAGE_FILE
  Query an (uninstalled) package PACKAGE_FILE.  The PACKAGE_FILE may be specified as an ftp or http style URL, in which case the package header will be
  downloaded  and  queried.
```

So if you use the `-p` option, then necessary the full package name.

( In the newest Fedora dist the recommended upgrade method is the FedUp tool:
https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Upgrading_Fedora_using_yum )